# How to prevent multiple ", " from being appended in the string

Tags: javascript

I am trying to basically check if the string ends with ", " then do not append another ", " . If the string does not end with ", " then append ", ". I just want one ", " in between two strings. However as I hit the "compute" button of my script several times (which basically iterates the key values & appends the comma's between strings) , I get multiple ", " between two strings. What I tried does not really work.

eg:

Expected is `abc, apple, pear, strawberry`
 even if I hit compute many times or one time

What I get after multiple clicks of compute button:

```
abc, , , , apple, , , , pear, , , , strawberry
```

Here's what I tried:

//Here obj[key][i] is the string

```
var lenson = obj[key][i].length;
if(1!=len-1){
if(obj[key][i].charAt(lenson-1) === " " && obj[key][i].charAt(lenson-2)=== ","){

}
else{
if(obj[key][i]!=""){
obj[key][i]+=", ";
}
}
li.appendChild(document.createTextNode( obj[key][i] ));

}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this check `'object' == typeof obj` is pretty useless to filter out non-objects, as everything but some literals is an object in JS.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you are getting your data from some sort of json object or similar. Since you are already looping over the keys, my advice would be to simple store them in an array. Then when you want to output them to string you just use `.join(",")`

```
var list = yourarray.join(",");
```

Comment: I actually tried to detect first if any string ends with ", " then do not append, else append. Is that the wrong logic?

Comment: Just try add items to javascript array and then just use above code to get comma seperated string

Comment: I would grab the values and remove any commas then temporarily store them in the array, and join them all at the end, that way you don't have to worry about whether or not commas exist

Comment: okay I'll do that but can you tell mewhats wrong with the code I've written? Thanks :)